# Highlight only first match

Tags: vim

With Vim, I want to highlight only the first match of an expression.

For instance, in the following text I want to highlight only the first a :

`bdjh abc olkd abc abc`

How can I realize this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make it explicit

```
/^.\{-}\zsa
```

This does:

- `^` (match start of line)
- `.\{-}` (match as few characters as possible)
- `\zs` (start of match)
- `a` (your pattern)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
/\v(.*a.*)@<!a
```

this should work.